# MySql view with parameter used with IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I would like to create a view in MySQL which can be used with different parameters.

Considering the following tables:

Table: `foo` Columns: `id (int)`, `barid (int)`

Table: `bar`
Columns: `id (int)`, `desc (varchar`

`foo.bar` is a foreign key to `bar.id`

I can now create a view and a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS int(11)
  RETURN @var;

CREATE VIEW view1 AS
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.barid = func();
```

Which can be used like this:

```
SET @var = 1;
SELECT * FROM view1;
```

What I'm looking for is a way to have a `IN`instead of the `=` operator in the view:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.barid IN (func());
```

Which I can then call something like this:

```
SET @var = '1,2';
SELECT * FROM view1;
```

Is there a way to get a view which can be used with different parameters, which are passed to an `IN` operator inside the view?

Comment: `bar` is a *table* according to your post. How can you use in a `WHERE` clause like `bar = func()`?

Comment: `bar` was also a column on `foo`. Changed this now to `barid` to make it clearer

Comment: Now `bar` table is not used in any way in your queries.

Comment: That's OK. Use case is that I want to recieve all entries from `foo` where `barid` for example is either `1` or `2`. I actually knew the IDs which I want to query.

Comment: So why do you need a function to do this? You can just hardcode the ids directly in your query.

Comment: I want to be able to use the view with different parameters. For example once I want to query all entries from `foo` where `barid` is either `1` or `2`, another time wher eit is `3` or `4`.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support table variables that would be the most suitable solution for your case. You can consider using a temporary table instead.